# Count the amount of items in a string[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I've googled this and can't find an answer.

Basically, I have a TextBox. I want to read a textbox line by line. I have this code:

```
string[] lst = txt.Split(new Char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This splits up every line but I can't modify or read it. How do I do this?

Comment: In what way can you not read it? It's an array. And which UI platform are you using? WinForms at least has a Lines property...

Comment: you can read the values of the lst with a simple foreach loop

Comment: I mean read as in have my C# code use it.

Comment: @chipperyman573 You can totally use it. Check this: `foreach(var s in lst) MessageBox.Show(s)`.

Comment: what do you mean by that.. please be more specific chipperyman573 try to save yourself from downvotes... show relevant code, be more specific, and formulate a question that will lead to less assumptions

Answer (score 1):

`lst.Length` will give you the number of elements in the array.  beyond that you're going to have to be more specific in your questio as to what you want to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand rightly, you need to read line by line, try this:

```
string[] lines = TextBox.Text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });
foreach(string line in lines)
{
   // read 'line' variable
}
```

With this, you will get an array of lines in your TexTbox. You also can access by index, using `lines[index]`.

you can use a `Length` property.

```
int total = lst.Length;
```

if you want to specify a char to count, you can use the `Count` extension method.

```
// add the Linq namespace.
using System.Linq;

int total = lst.Count(c => c == "c");
```

Comment: I don't need the length, I need to take line one, read it, line two, read it, etc...

Comment: Felipe Oriani you have a typo in your Spli

Comment: Thank you DJ KRAZE,. I correct my code. :) Take a look at my edits.

Comment: chipperyman573, is the textbox a multiline textbox..? take a screen shot and add it to your question...

Comment: Yes, DJ. Also, your code outputs: 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Text.get' . System.Windows.Forms... doesn't exist.

Comment: Nevermind, I replaced TextBox with my textbox name

Comment: I have not posted any code chipperyman573

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your TextBox has the `MultiLine` property set to True.
You can get the lines of your TextBox simply with

```
string[] lines = textBox1.Lines;
```

already splitted at the newline char.
Then you could iterate over then

```
for(int x=0; x<lines.Length; x++)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines[0])
         // process...
}
```

the loop using for is preferable to using foreach if you need to change the line

Comment: So then lines[0] would get the first line on my question?

Comment: chipperyman573 here is a good link that you should read it's a tutorial I would suggest reading it http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html

Comment: Yes also `for(x=0;x<lines.Length;x++)`

Answer (score 0):

```
string line = null;
using(var sr = new StringReader(txt))
    while((line=sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        Console.WriteLine(line)
```

Comment: Could you add a few words to your answer? Try to describe what was the problem and why the proposed solution will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't lie within the code but in your question.

You need to show more of it, specially how lst is used after that statement.
The following property will give you what you need.

```
lst.Length //holds the number of strings in lst.
```

You can acess each string with:

```
string valueInIndex_i = lst[i];
```

You can iterate throught its contents with:

```
foreach(string thisString in lst)
{
     //do stuff with thisString
}
```